# How to find all child elements with a class and check if any are empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and need to check to make sure any child inputs of a fieldset are empty. How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

if any fields with .required are empty
  -> there are fields that have not been filled out
if all fields with .required have been filed out
  -> they have all been filed out

Comment: if your validating data please consider using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your fields by form id and class name.  Then use `.filter()` to reduce your set to include only the fields that have not been filled out:

```
var emptyFields = $("#myForm .required").filter(function()
{
    return $(this).val() == "";
});
```

If you don't want to do anything with the fields, but just need a boolean:

```
var anyEmptyFields = !!emptyFields.length;
```

Comment: I recommend: `return this.value && $.trim(this.value) === '';`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var emptyRequiredFields = jQuery("#post-form .required:input").not("[value]");
```

Comment: My bad, I can undo my downvote if you will edit your post.  I'm surprised that this works - changing the value shouldn't change the attribute, just the property.  And, in fact, `input.hasAttribute("value")` returns false in Chrome and FF even if text is entered, as I expected.  I guess jQuery isn't *actually* checking attributes, but properties as well.  I actually tested before I downvoted, but there was a bug in my test that returned a false positive.  Heh, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <fieldset id="myForm">
            <input type="text" required="true" /><br />
            <input type="check" required="true" /><br />
            <input type="radio" required="true" /><br />

            <input type="text" required="false" /><br />
            <input type="check" required="" /><br />
            <input type="radio"  /><br />
            <button onclick="$('#myForm').find('input[required=true]').after('<span>null</span>');">Check</button>
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
$("form[name=form_name] .required").each(function(index,e){
    if(e.value == ''){
     alert(e.name+' field is required!');   
    }
});
```